# Socket.io/nodejs problems with emit

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Im currently working on a little test game and notice some huge delaying in the information sended by socket emit.
The contexto is that o have a player that can shoot and every time he shoots he send a emit for the server with the information of the bullet, and the server broadcasts to the other players. 
My question is if this workflow of a player sending a lot of emits can slow down the execution of the socket.io.
Other thing that i notice is that sometimes a console.log inside a socket emit dont show up in the console for some time(idk if this two things have the same cause)

```
Client emiting..
shoot(){
  socket.emit('newBullet', bullet.position, bullet.direction,bullet.damage);
}

Server receiving emits..
socket.on('newBullet', function(position, direction, damage){
      socket.broadcast.emit('spawnBullet', position, direction, damage);
});

Other clients receiving broadcast..
socket.on('spawnBullet', function(position, direction, damage){
      const b = new bullet(position, direction, damage);
      player.bullets.push(b);
});
```

Comment: It's unlikely people can help without seeing the relevant portions of your code.  Questions about problems with your  code SHOULD include the relevant portion of the code inserted into the question directly and formatted properly as code.

Comment: sorry, i edited the question with the pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

> My question is if this workflow of a player sending a lot of emits can slow down the execution of the socket.io.

Yes, it can.

It all depends upon whether your server can keep up and whether the clients can keep up.  For a given server, there certainly exists a rate of messages from all the clients that it will have trouble keeping up and doing any other things it is supposed to be doing.

Likewise, if lots of clients are all sending messages to the server causing it to broadcast to all the other clients, that can quickly add up to a ton of messages for the server to send and clients to process.

There exist smart designs that detect when the rate of update is too quick and they do something to alleviate that (perhaps skipping messages that have already been superceded by other ones in the queue).  Imagine the same concept as a mouse driver that attempts to show the mouse moving at every pixel across the screen, but if you move it fast enough, it skips intervening mouse renders and only shows the newest position at the time it renders the mouse.  You probably want to do something similar when there are too many updates flying around.

> Other thing that i notice is that sometimes a console.log inside a socket emit dont show up in the console for some time(idk if this two things have the same cause)

That just sounds like lag.  Either the server or a client gets overwhelmed and data is coming in faster than it can keep up with.

Comment: Thanks for this response, and i think this logic would be very usefull in the part of sending the position of the player for the others. But i cant think in a way to aply this logic to bullets, because when one player shot this information have to be sended to all of them right?

Comment: @Gobbs - How to skip or coalesce messages is very application-specific.  It all depends upon what unnecessary or redundant information is in the server queue waiting to be sent to clients that can be eliminated or can coalesce multiple messages into one summary message, thus reducing the traffic.  It could also be that your clients or server need to be made more efficient in their calculations so they can process more messages.